# Undefined reference to hash function

Tags: c, hash, codeblocks, undefined-reference

I'm trying to run a program in Code::Blocks, and in my program I have used the hash functions, such as `hsearch` and `hcreate`, but Code::Blocks seems to not allow them.

I have the header:

```
#include <search.h>
```

included already, but errors such as `"undefined reference to 'hsearch' "`  still comes up.

Is there anyway to allow these functions to run in Code::Blocks at all?

Comment: "*undefined reference*" is linker error.

Comment: Where did you get the library from? It seems like it is misconfigured, and the linker can't link it.

Comment: @meskobalazs The search.h was obtained from the man page [Here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hcreate)

Comment: Are you running linux or windows? The function is in the standard libc. On linux it should run "out of the box". See https://ideone.com/mr06W3 I just pasted the example from the man page into.

Comment: `search.h` is not a library, but a so called "header file", which in fact is a C source file. It only provides the "interface" of what a specific object or library implements, so that the compiler knows about it. When the compiler is done in a final step all objects/libraries needed are linked together with what the compiler produced, to create the final program.

Comment: @kwarnke I'm running on windows, hence using codeblock IDE to do my coding. I think is the problem, but is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Header files are just containing the *declarations*. You need to have the libraries installed, which are containing the *implementation*.

And that what it is telling you. It found the declarations just fine, however the linker did not find the libraries, hence the linkage error.

On Linux, the `search.h` and its implementation is part of the `libc`, so it is already ready to use. On Windows, however, you need to get a binary version of it, set up the library path for Code::Blocks, and use the linker options in the settings.

Comment: Ahhh yes, this is what I'm looking for. I'll search on the web a bit, and see if I can find it and get it working. Thank you so much!